# Why does android:layout_height can only be either fill parent or wrap content?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

Why does [android:layout_height](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_height) can only either fill parent minus padding or wrap content? What if I want minus all other childs?

For example, can I make this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If You want to fill all available space just set `height = "0dp"` and set constraint to propper View which You want to set height.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="TextView Top Half"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is a layout from Your image.

Answer (score 0):

You can archieve this with a `ConstraintLayout`. You can first define your buttons in the bottom, and then set the height of your top view to match the parent minus your buttons thanks to this:

> app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttons"

In my example I've put a `Barrier` that allows the top view to have it's bottom above all buttons, even if all buttons don't have the same height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button_a"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
         android:padding="10dp"
         android:text="Button A"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_b"/>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button_b"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
         android:padding="20dp"
         android:text="Button A"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_a"/>

     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
         android:id="@+id/button_barrier"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         app:barrierDirection="top"
         app:constraint_referenced_ids="button_a, button_b" />

     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_barrier"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

         <!-- your top half here -->

     </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My example gives you something like this:

[image: layout]

(Barrier is represented with the dashed line. It will be invisible when you run your code)

Answer (score -1):

```
                          textColor="0xFFFFFFFF";
                          id="line";
                          layout_gravity="center";
                          textSize="11.5sp";
                          layout_width="25%w";
                          layout_height="wrap";
                          layout_marginBottom="3dp";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).